# Specify amount of memory to be used when running my app within IntelliJ 2020

Tags: java, intellij-idea, memory

While developing my app within IntelliJ 2020, I want to see how my app runs in a limited amount of memory.

With a standalone Java app in a JAR, I could specify `-Xmx1024M` on the command-line while launching my app.

But when I am developing the app within the IntelliJ IDE, how does one specify a limit on the amount of memory to be allocated to the app when run from a `Run/Debug Configuration` within IntelliJ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drop down on run and select Edit configuration then there is VM Options input where you can add your Xmx parameter.

## IntelliJ 2020.3 and later

Click `Modify options` to display a pop-up menu of various sets of options. Choose `Add VM Options` to alter the panel’s display to show a `VM options` text field.

[image: Screenshot of IntelliJ 2020.3 early-access > Run/Debug Configurations > Modify options pop-up menu.]

## Earlier versions

You can also get there by pressing Alt+Shift+F10 , then press 0 to display the Edit Configuration dialog.

Step 1:

[image],

Step 2: fill the VM options

[image]

Comment: That `Run/Debug Configurations` has changed significantly in IntelliJ 2020.3 early-access, re-arranged to show/hide various options via a pop-up menu.